# Is a transistor appropriate for this?

Tags: transistors

I have a thermal camera whose external shutter doesn't close when commanded to by the camera. I think it is a current issue. Something is fried or worn out within the camera's electronics. The shutter works fine as I can get it to close by applying Vcc to the correct pin on the shutter. When the camera commands pin A to go high, it goes high, but all that happens is there is a very high pitched whine heard from the camera and the shutter never closes. Vcc is 3v, and when A goes high it is also 3v. How would I make it so that when A goes high, a switch is closed connecting Vcc to A?

[image]

Comment: If something is "fried or worn," then it seems that your best bet would be to address than rather than adding circuitry.

Comment: Sure, but we can't in this situation. It's within the tiny, tiny, sealed thermal camera.

Comment: Uhh I smell a short circuit here... potentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftrMPD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I can't add anything between the black box (the camera) and the shutter. I can only use the fact that A goes high to initiate some action (like the closing of a switch).

Comment: Then without more details on the interface, I cannot help